# different HERE APIs - get layer attributes

Tags: here-api

I am using HERE API to get additional information about geographical points through Layers and their attributes. I see there are two ways to go to get these information:

1. m.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/matchroute.json/?routemode=car&attributes=... with attribute list in the request:

> attributes=ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn(HPX,HPY,HPZ,SLOPES,HEADINGS,CURVATURES,REFNODE_LINKCURVHEADS,NREFNODE_LINKCURVHEADS),LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCn(ISO_COUNTRY_CODE,VEHICLE_TYPES,URBAN,TRANSPORT_VERIFIED,TO_REF_NUM_LANES,FROM_REF_NUM_LANES),LINK_ATTRIBUTE2_FCn(FOUR_WHEEL_DRIVE,SCENIC_ROUTE,PARKING_LOT_ROAD,PARKING_AVAILABILITY,PRIORITY_ROAD,CARPOOL_ROAD,REVERSIBLE,EXPRESS_LANE,TRANSITION_AREA,EXPANDED_INCLUSION,DELIVERY_ROAD,TRUCK_ROAD_TYPE,BICYCLE_ACCESS,BICYCLE_PROTECTION_TYPE,BICYCLE_TRAVEL_DIR_OVERRIDE,SURFACE_TYPE,GENERALISED_BICYCLE_PATH),TRAFFIC_SIGN_FCn(VEHICLE_TYPES,TRAFFIC_SIGN_TYPE)

2. https://m.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/matchroute.json API + https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/tiles.json to get attributes of layers

What is the difference in these approaches? Will all attribute values be the same for same longitude-latitude points input?

Answer (score 0):

Both API used for specific use cases.

Route matching is an alternative to calling PDE(Fleet advanced data set) along the route, for selected use cases.

> When to retrieve attributes directly in the route match call and when
> to fetch them afterwards from PDE?

In general, a matched route spans a few PDE tiles only, because the major part of a route is on functional class 1 roads (motorways) that are stored in PDE layers with large tiles. Hence, after a route match, the distinct set of tiles to load from PDE should rarely exceed 20 or 30, resulting in a few PDE requests, because each PDE request can ask for multiple tiles of multiple layers. The advantage of using PDE is that the retrieved full tile content can be cached for up to a month, and hence repeated transmission is avoided, if the assets are repeatedly driving in similar areas, which is usually the case.

However, asking for the attributes directly in the route match request is more simple on client side, and only the data of the links along the route are actually transferred.